# TestStack.White window from handle or AutomationElement

Tags: c#, automationelement, teststack

I have been unable to get a teststack window object by only using an automationelement or window handle.  By looking at source code, I can see that this functionality is protected.

Does anybody know of an easy way to do this. Without finding the app first then using window finder function as i already know the window.

Thanks Dan

Comment: what do you mean you already know the window? the title of the window you want? if so, you can get the window with title using: `application.GetWindow("Window Title Here");`

Comment: I mean I already know the window handle (hwnd) and therefore can get the AutomationElement for the window. However when trying to use teststack I don't want to have to first get the app and then loop through all windows using title etc. Looking at the source code. The winfowfactory has a Create method which takes an AutomationElement but this is private.